# Word-wrap issue in cell in excel file after export from laravel datatables

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

**Hello Dear,**

I have query in my code, I am using yajra/laravel-datatables package `("yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^9.0")`. I want to export Laravel data-table same as table view. Means I can't export data-table with word-wrap text. Please visit below screenshot so you can sure about it.

**Screenshot 1:** This one is the view of my laravel data-table. That I need same as during export in excel file.

https://prnt.sc/vgji9s

**Screenshot 2:** This one is my current view of excel file.

https://prnt.sc/vgj83k

https://prnt.sc/vgj8nn

Please check it and give me a suggestion for it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use column formatting. You should use ShouldAutoSize.

[Read More about column formatting](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.0/exports/column-formatting.html)

You can use ShouldAutoSize in your export class. sample code of export class is as below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\Member;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;

class MemberTwoExport implements FromView, ShouldAutoSize
{
/**
* @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
*/


   public function view() : View
   {
       $member = Member::get();
       return view('Your blade file')->with('member', $member);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I'll try it and let you know if any problem.

Comment: Hello Rajen, I review your given code and match it with my existing code but I have blanck file of `WithColumnFormatting`. I didn't export a invoice I need to export employee timelog report. Please see below screenshot and let me know What can I do next. 

https://prnt.sc/vslbi9

Comment: i m editing my answer with sample code, which may help you.

Comment: In this code you describe `member` model so which model I can use for it?

Comment: If possible, please give me your mail id so I can mail you my current code.

Comment: laravel.rajen@gmail.com

Comment: I mail a code of controller, blade file and data-table file.